# Is it possible to get the QNH value in Austria using a web service?

Tags: altimeter, website, qnh

I got a altimeter sensor which can be connected to a computer and can be adjusted by the QNH!

I need the QNH for Austria, I figured out that the current QNH of the airports are streamed via radio.

Are QNH provided as text format or even better web service, so I can fetch mine automatically for transparent altimeter setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current QNH at an airport is included in METARs so you can grab it form there. There are a few online services to retrieve the METAR automatically, such as [this one](https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=LOWW&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true) (using Vienna airport as an example).

The latest METAR when I wrote this answer was:

```
LOWW 281050Z 14010KT 9999 FEW040 SCT065 BKN300 04/M03 Q1012 NOSIG
```

which shows a QNH of 1012.

Note that depending on the country the format may vary slightly, but in Austria (and European countries) you should always find a `Qxxx` value in the report.